# 24V LED Lights with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I need help on determining how I can control 24VDC Auer Stack lights with an Arduino. I intend to activate these lights with a RF control and monitor them via IoT; the latter is just something else, not my main concern right now. However, I don´t know if I need to use normal relays, solid state relays or MOSFETs such as an IRF520. 
The lights are 24V, consume around 22mA-33mA, they are pre-wired and only have the 4 wires (from the amount of lights I intend to use) and a common wire.

Thanks in advance!

---

Thank you for your quick response! I can see the IRF520 might be too much. What about the IRF520 arduino module, it has lower current and voltage rates, do you think it might work?

Answer (score 0):

All that differs between those LEDs and 12V LEDs is the voltage. You do exactly the same as you would do with 12V LEDs - you just make sure the components you use are rated for *at least* 24V.

The IRF520 is overkill for this application. It's rated for 100V and 9A - far more than you need. But that's not to say it won't work - it'll work just fine. But you don't *need* one as big or beefy.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I can see the IRF520 might be too much. What about the IRF520 arduino module, it has lower current and voltage rates, do you think it might work?

Comment: As long as the voltage rating is at least 24V, sure. It's probably the connectors and copper clearances on the board that dictate the voltage rating more than the MOSFET.

Comment: An IRF520 Arduino module is just a IRF520 on a PC board, with screw terminals, a connector, and an indicator LED. It doesn't add any real value over using a "bare" IRF520, and has the same restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the IRF520 is a logic level MOSFET. You need one that can be driven to satuation with 5V. I've used this one from Adafruit for several projects: https://www.adafruit.com/product/355

It worked fine. It's also overkill, but so what?

(It looks like that same part number, IRLB8721, is available from several other manufacturers for cheaper than the Adadfruit part.)

It's dirt simple to use. You can drive the gate directly from an Arduino digital pin. It will handle plenty of current and up to 60V, so it should meet your needs.

Comment: At the currents involved the R_DSON even for a non-logic-level MOSFET like this doesn't really figure that much. It could be 100Ω@5V and you really wouldn't notice.  Personally I use STD19N3LLH6AG for my more powerful driving requirements - but then I can't remember the last time I used a through-hole component...

Comment: Pardon my ignorance (I am not an electronics expert). I thought the IRF520 Arduino Module was logic level (by the fact that it is driven by an Arduino). What do you mean by "driven to situation with 5V"..

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. (Must have been auto-correct.) The phrase I intended to type is "driven to saturation" That means fully turned on. I don't know if the Arduino module boosts the gate voltage somehow. Getting an Arduino "module" is a little silly, given that all you need is a logic-level MOSFET, which costs less than a dollar US. There's no need for a PC board or other stuff.